# Moving first item in linked list to end C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I need to move the first item in a linked list to the end of the list. My problem is I'm going in to an infinite loop. When I remove the cause for the infinite loop (`tail -> link != NULL`; in the for loop), I get a seg fault. So, looking for ideas on how to get this code to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
  string data;
  Node *link;
};

class Lilist
{
  public:
    Lilist() {head = NULL;}
    void add(string item);
    void show();
    void move_front_to_back();
    Node* search(string target);

  private:
    Node *head;
};

int main()
{
  Lilist L1, L2;
  string target;

  L1.add("Charlie"); //add puts a name at the end of the list
  L1.add("Lisa");
  L1.add("Drew");
  L1.add("Derrick");
  L1.add("AJ");
  L1.add("Bojian");

  cout << "Now showing list One:\n";
  L1.show(); // displays the list (This function displayed the list properly)
  cout << "\n";

  L1.move_front_to_back();
  L1.move_front_to_back();
  L1.show();
  cout << "\n";

  return(0);
}


void Lilist::add(string item)
{
  Node *temp;
  if(head == NULL)
  {
    head = new Node;
    head -> data = item;
    head -> link = NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    for(temp = head; temp -> link != NULL; temp = temp -> link)
        ;
    temp -> link = new Node;
    temp = temp -> link;
    temp -> data = item;
    temp -> link = NULL;
  }
}

void Lilist::show()
{
  for(Node *temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp -> link)
    std::cout << temp -> data << " ";
}

void Lilist::move_front_to_back()
{
  Node *temp;
  Node *tail;

  temp = head;

  for(tail = head; tail != NULL; tail = tail -> link)
    ;

  head = head -> link;
  tail -> link = temp;
  temp -> link = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please. Maybe the list is corrupt already when you start?

Comment: I can't type everything out currently but I know the list isn't corrupt. This is the second half of the program. The first half adds 6 nodes and then outputs the list. And I don't remember the code I had in this segment but I at one point had it where it was "deleting" the nodes it moved @Angew

Comment: If you don't have the necessary information, there is no way to help you and no reason to keep this question here. Just for the record: This smells like homework, too.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt You're right that without a MCVE, this is unanswerable. But there is no problem with a question being homework; it just has to be as well-formed as any other question.

Comment: @user4476295 Can you verify in the debugger that your last element's `link == NULL`? I bet it's not.

Comment: I honestly figured this was all the necessary information seeing as how the issue lies in the function. And yes it is, HOWEVER, i'm not asking you to write the code for me, I'm asking for extra eyes to spot and error that I can't find since I'm new to linked lists. I didn't think that was an issue but if it is I'll delete the question. @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: As it stands, delete the question. However, it would be much better if you improved the question so that it contains a minimal but complete example that shows the issues. Doing that has two advantages: Firstly, you learn to extract the relevent parts of a problem. Secondly, that allows others to spot the error or learn from your problem. Typically, you will find the error yourself in that process.

Comment: There is not all necessary information. The function, as written, *works.* [Here's proof](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c240b4932a16637f).

Comment: @user4476295 You have a runtime issue, thus we need something to run to duplicate the error.  We have no idea what values those variables you've posted have, whether your linked list is properly constructed, etc.

Comment: I've added the main function in to it. As far as I understand that should be good enough with comments explaining the purpose of the functions that work.

Comment: Can you please follow the link I provided, read up what an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, and post one? Something we could just paste to Coliru or Ideone and see the behvaiour ourselves. I think I know what the problem is, but I can't be sure without seeing *all* relevant code (like the definitions of `Lilist`, `Node` and `add()`).

Comment: @user4476295 You're working under the assumption that all of those other functions that you didn't post that manipulate the list are working correctly.  We can't assume this.

Comment: @user4476295 And to show it works with string data: http://ideone.com/2Q4puc

Comment: I apologize for just catching on but I'm obviously new here. I BELIEVE I have given what was asked. This file gives only the information needed to run the program and give the error. It can be directly copied and pasted and run.

Comment: I can't see why this was actually put on hold. Now that the OP has provided an MCVE, it's a pretty decent question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in how you compute `tail`. Notice this (unrelated lines omitted for brevity):

```
for(tail = head; tail != NULL; tail = tail -> link)
  ;
tail -> link = temp;
```

Notice that the `for` loop will only terminate once `tail` is `NULL`. Then, you dereference `tail` ... which is null.

So change the `for` loop condition:

```
for (tail = head; tail->link != NULL; tail = tail->link)
  ;
```

This will find the last element in the list, instead of flowing off the end.

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a324d5f6575abf97)

Comment: huh. I could have sworn I put that and it gave me an infinite loop. It worked. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, this would be a lot easier if `Lilist` had a `tail` member that it kept updated at all times, just like its `head` member, then it would not have to waste time hunting for the `tail` every time it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Angew already explained why your original code was failing.  I would suggest an alternative approach - give `Lilist` a `tail` member that is managed alongside its `head` member.  Then you don't have to hunt for the `tail` whenever you need it, you always know exactly which `Node` is the current `tail`, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    string data;
    Node *next;

    Node(string s);
};

class Lilist
{
public:
    Lilist();
    ~Lilist();
    void add(string item);
    void show();
    void move_front_to_back();
    Node* search(string target);

private:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
};

Node::Node(string s)
    : data(s), next(NULL)
{
}

Lilist::Lilist()
    : head(NULL), tail(NULL)
{
}

Lilist::~Lilist()
{
    for(Node *temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
        delete temp;
}

void Lilist::add(string item)
{
    Node *temp = new Node(item);

    if (head == NULL)
        head = temp;

    if (tail != NULL)
        tail->next = temp;

    tail = temp;
}

void Lilist::show()
{
    for(Node *temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
        cout << temp->data << " ";
}

void Lilist::move_front_to_back()
{
    if (head == tail)
        return;

    Node *temp = head;

    head = temp->next;
    temp->next = NULL;

    tail->next = temp;
    tail = temp;
}

Node* Lilist::search(string target)
{
    for(Node *temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
    {
        if (temp->data == target)
            return temp;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```